# Is there an option to see in Results Fields "Set By: Name", but to see the Internal ID of the employee instead of the name?

Tags: formula, netsuite, saved-searches

In Netsuite Saved Search in Results, I would like to see who create the record, but I would like to see the internal ID instead of the name.
Is there any way "Set by: Name" setting in 'System Notes' field to show Internal ID of the employee rather than name
Can I use formula instead of this field?

Thank you in advance

System Notes: Set by

Comment: `{systemnotes.user.id}` ?

Comment: @Jdg50 Hi Jdg, Thank you very much. Just to confirm. Do you mean field to be Formula (text) and this to be the formula itself?

Comment: .id will give the internal id of a list/record field instead of the display name

Comment: Yes, that should work. I don't have access to a Netsuite environment at the moment or I'd check myself. But from memory, {systemnotes.user} should work at least. Getting the ID would probably be {systemnotes.user.id}. You'd have to do a bit of filtering to ensure you're getting the user that created the record and not modified it.

Comment: Hi Nathan, It works for {systemnotes.name}, but not for {systemnotes.user.id}. I have this error: ERROR: Field Not Found.

Comment: Do you mean systemnotes.name or systemnotes.user that works?

Comment: @Jdg50, Thanks, mate! It works for {systemnotes.name} but not for {systemnotes.user.id}. I'm getting this error message that field not found.

Comment: What about {systemnotes.name.id} ?

Comment: I believe system notes stores text, not a record, so .id won't work.

Comment: {systemnotes.name} works and {systemnotes.user.id}not

Comment: @Jdg50 name id works, mate. You are a legend. :) Thank you very very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put this in an answer,

Using `{systemnotes.name.id}` using Formula (text) as your field type will get you the answer. You can test this as `{systemnotes.name}` will just give you the user. You'll have to do a bit of filtering to ensure you're grabbing the right user.

In the past, I've used workflows to fill a custom "Created By" field and grabbed my information from there.

Comment: Once again,  Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can mark it as accepted with the green check mark :) I'm happy to have helped! Glad you got it working.